# Backbone infinite Collection Fetch call for desired response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

i am calling a rest API which trigger site refresh on server. Then i need to call another API(another collection fetch) to check site refresh is completed or not. i required to call second API until i get siteRefresh="completed". How can I do this in backbone way.

My view code is like this

```
define(['collections/firstCollection',
 'collections/secondCollection',
], function(firstCollection, secondCollection) {
var memAccId;
var refreshView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName : 'div',
    className : 'refresh-wrap',
    initialize : function() {           
        var self = this;    
            self.collection = new firstCollection();
            self.collection.fetch({
                timeout : 50000,
                type : "POST",
                data : data,                    
                success : function(response) {
                    var result = response.toJSON();
                    if ( typeof result[0].Id !== "undefined") {
                memAccId=result[0].Id;
                    $(self.$el).trigger('onAccountId');
                        }

                    },
                    error : function(request, status, error) {
                        console.log("ERROR - first Collection on fetch error.");

                    }

                });         
        },
        events : {
            'onAccountId' : 'getRefreshInfo'
        },
        getRefreshInfo : function() {
        var self = this;
            self.collection = new secondCollection();
            self.collection.fetch({
                timeout : 30000,
                type : 'POST',
                data : {"Id":memAccId},
                success : function(response) {
            if(response.refreshStatus !=="REFRESH_COMPLETED"){
                  //  self.collection.fetch();
                  //how to call this collection fetch until i get refreshStatus = 
"REFRESH_COMPLETED"
             }
            },
                    error:function(request, status, error){

            }
            });
            }
        }
    });
    return refreshView;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    define(['collections/firstCollection',
     'collections/secondCollection',
    ], function(firstCollection, secondCollection) {
    var memAccId;
    var refreshView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName : 'div',
        className : 'refresh-wrap',
        initialize : function() {           
            var self = this;    
                self.collection = new firstCollection();
                self.collection.fetch({
                    timeout : 5000,
                    type : "POST",
                    data : data,                    
                    success : function(response) {
                        var result = response.toJSON();
                        if ( typeof result[0].Id !== "undefined") {
                    memAccId=result[0].Id;
//call getRefreshInfo in every 5 seconds                     
  refresh = setInterval(function() {
                self.getRefreshInfo ();
            }, 5000);

                        },
                        error : function(request, status, error) {
                            console.log("ERROR - first Collection on fetch error.");

                        }

                    });         
            }            
            getRefreshInfo : function() {
            var self = this;
                self.collection = new secondCollection();
                self.collection.fetch({
                    timeout : 30000,
                    type : 'POST',
                    data : {"Id":memAccId},
                    success : function(response) {
                if(response.refreshStatus !=="REFRESH_COMPLETED"){
//stop getRefreshInfo infinite call once you get status REFRESH_COMPLETED
clearInterval(refresh);

                 }
                },
                        error:function(request, status, error){

                }
                });
                }
            }
        });
        return refreshView;
    });`enter code here`
```